# Sticky div at bottom of viewport after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a sticky *footer* element in a left hand column of a webpage. The right hand column will have dynamic content so I can't put an exact height to any element(except for viewport height). What I'd like to happen is the *footer* is placed below the viewport until a user starts scrolling and then the *footer* element is fixed at the bottom of the viewport.

I have a forked [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu3hf4dk/) that works but breaks the content if it is taller than navigation. I've also tried using [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), but I can't wrap everything together because of the same issue.

What I've found so far.

```
var $buzz = $('#buzz'),
    viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
    buzzHeight = 182,
    buzzTop = $buzz.offset().top + buzzHeight,
    buzzPosition = buzzTop - viewportHeight;

$(window).bind("resize.browsersize", function () {

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
    buzzHeight = 182,
    buzzTop = $buzz.offset().top + buzzHeight,
    buzzPosition = buzzTop - viewportHeight;

}).trigger("resize.browsersize");

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= buzzPosition) {
        $buzz.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: 0
        });   
    } else {
        $buzz.removeAttr("style");
    }

});
```

Comment: do you have a live example?

Comment: Here is a better example of what I need. This example works except I need the element to stick as soon as it hits the bottom of the viewport instead of scrolling all the way to the top and then appearing at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/3vffmu3p/

Answer (score 0):

In the events that cause the divs on the left to resize, call `$(window).scroll();` and it will reposition the sticky footer.

```
$('.change').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css("height", "+=50px");
    $(window).scroll();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Here is a better example of what I need. This example works except I need the element to stick as soon as it hits the bottom of the viewport instead of scrolling all the way to the top and then appearing at the bottom. jsfiddle.net/3vffmu3p